# Excel not recognizing named ranges

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I have been recently working on a personal project that includes linking a form to a google spreadsheet, the process goes as follows: the form accepts certain inputs "text strings" and the responses reflects eventually on the spreadsheet. I have created several named ranges matching all the inputs from responses and every named range its own value. the problem i have been facing that excel isn't recognizing the named ranges.
lets say the input from a response will be "Book", which is a named range referencing a price, is in cell B2. when I try =Sum(B2) the result is 0.
tried offset when creating the named range, also tried the indirect function.
what should I change ?

Comment: You seem to be confused between Googlesheets and Excel. Names defined in one may not work in the other.

Comment: @SolarMike actually i'm not, I just forgot to mention that all i'm doing is on excel at the moment, so it's all about excel.

Comment: So what is the Google spreadsheet for?

Comment: @SolarMike I mentioned it to explain the whole text strings inputs and form thing, that's all
the problem i'm facing is with excel not recognizing the named ranges set

Comment: So, if you name a range there's no way Excel 'won't recognize' it (as you put it). Given that, I suspect you're seeing one thing but misinterpreting that as something else. Can only recommend going back basics. Create a fresh (new book) minimal mock-up of what you're doing and prove to yourself it works. Then work back/build out/compare to find what's wrong.

Comment: @Spinner already did that several times, I'm quite sure it's not recognizing it
the only case in which it does is when i type it directly (as in =NamedRange for example). yet if I already have it as an input in a cell and I tried referencing this cell ( =F5 etc), the results returns as 0

Comment: Are your numbers formatted as text?  That would return 0 as the sum - an undefined name would return a `#NAME?` error.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes; text strings referring to numerical values.
is there a way to make the function calculate the original value instead of returning as 0 ?

Comment: Look into `VALUE` :)

Comment: @Spinner elaborate further please ?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your sheet, because I don't understand "I have created several named ranges matching all the inputs from responses and every named range its own value"

Comment: Ok... read help on using `VALUE` in excel. It's for converting numbers stored as text to numbers. Alternately, convert your numbers stored as text manually. You can do that with `Copy` and `Paste Special...` and `Values` (as long a the target cell aren't formatted as text).

Comment: Is this a confusion between a text string "Book" and a range name Book? if your Form returns the string Book to say cell D4 and you have a Range Name called Book that refers to cell B2 which contains 99.99 then the formula =INDIRECT(D4) will return 99.99 and the formula =Book will return 99.99 and the formula =INDIRECT("Book") will return 99.99 and the formula =D4 will return Book